# R: Getting columns with rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I'm able to get the columns that I want using rvest. Then, I want to combine all the columns into a data frame so that I can have a list of companies with their respective name, sector, address, url and phone.

#Here are my codes:

```
url_base <- "https://www.yellowpages.my/listing/results.php?keyword=&where=selangor&screen=%d"
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
```

#**scrape** for first two pages:

```
map_df(1:2, function(i) {
  cat(".")
  pg <- read_html(sprintf(url_base, i))
  data.frame(
    name=html_text(html_nodes(pg, "div.cbp-vm-company >a")),
    sector=html_text(html_nodes(pg, "div.cbp-vm-address > a")),
    address=html_text(html_nodes(pg, "div.cbp-vm-address")),
    url=html_attr(html_nodes(pg, ".cbp-vm-company  > a"),'href'),
    phone=html_attr(html_nodes(pg, ".cbp-vm-cta > span"),'data-content'),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
}) -> List
```

However, there are some problems that I can't solve it. Can you please help?

1. phone: Can I know how to exclude "NA" from the data frame?
2. url: There are other pages that do not have the info for this particular column (e.g. "https://www.yellowpages.my/listing/results.php?keyword=&where=selangor&screen=10946"). Can I put NA for this particular column? So that it allows me to combine it with other columns
3. name: Some of the pages (e.g. "https://www.yellowpages.my/listing/results.php?keyword=&where=selangor&screen=10946") will have to use "html_nodes("div.cbp-vm-companytext")" to extract the company name instead of "html_nodes("div.cbp-vm-company >a")". How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem you can change the path of the attribute to `phone=html_attr(html_nodes(pg, ".left-border+ .left-border"),'data-content')`

This selects just the phone element where previously it included the information element as well. I would recommend using a tool like [SelectorGadget](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb?hl=en) which allows you to interactively select the elements you need. This may help answer your other problems. I will try again later for the rest.

Comment: Thanks @rjpat. Still not able to solve the problem for #2 - url/sector as i'm not able to combine all the columns to a list as there are missing data in url/sector. 

Have tried to use ifelse statement but is not working.

sector=ifelse(html_text(html_nodes(pg, "div.cbp-vm-address > a"))=="","NA",html_text(html_nodes(pg, "div.cbp-vm-address > a")))

Answer (score 1):

For your third question  you can use css Or syntax to match on either

```
html_nodes("div.cbp-vm-company >a,div.cbp-vm-companytext")
```